# C++ pointer concepts

Tags: c++, pointers

so, I've got my pointer:

```
int *p = new int(10);
```

And I print out the following things:

```
&p which is: 0xbdee018
 p which is: 0xb8c254b0
```

`&p` stands for the address of the pointer, and `p` is stands for the address of the mapped value by the pointer itself.

Is that correct, or is it the very opposite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right .
`&p` stand for address of pointer and `p` give address where it point.

Answer (score 5):

Yes exactly. `&` gives the address of the element.

So

- `p` gives the value currently *inside* the variable - `p` being a pointer, you get a pointer (to an int)
- `&p` returns the address of `p`

Graphically

```
  p value = 0xb8c254b0 --> int x 10
  ^
  |-------- 0xbdee018
```

Answer (score 2):

`p` denotes the address of an integer, e.g. `int*`.

`*p` denotes the integer stored at `p` (dereferencing), e.g. `int`.

`&p` denotes the address of the pointer `p`. If `p` would be an `int`, you would obtain a pointer-to-int by referencing `p`, e.g. `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're totally correct.

&p is the the address of the pointer or you can say a pointer of your pointer.

p is the pointer of an array of 10 int elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting thing in the correct way. A pointer has to be stored somewhere, so it has an address too. Try to see the memory with the debugger, by using the address you shown in your example, point to the address

```
0xbdee018
```

and check the bytes, you should see, in some orders the bytes:

```
0xb8c254b0
```

ie `p`.

The order of the bytes depends on the 'endianity' of the cpu you are using

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is a `variable` that stores `address of other variable` that the pointer points to. This variable itself also has memory address, which is `&p` in this case if variable name is `p`. So:

> "&p" is stands for the address of the pointer, and "p" is stands for the address of the mapped value by the pointer itself.

You are right. Besides, `*p` will get you the value of the object it points to. You may find [Binky Pointer Fun Video](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems, that you got it right.

To ilustrate:

```
int i = 42;
int * pointer_to_i = &i;
```

Then:

```
i == 42 // obvious
&i == pointer_to_i // address, where a value 42 is stored
                   // for the sake of example, let's assume
                   // that &i == 0x12345678
&pointer_to_i // address, where a value 0x12345678 is stored
```

Additionally:

- `&<name>` gets the address of a variable `<name>` (you can assign that to a pointer);
- `*<pointer>` *dereferences* the `<pointer>`, that is retreives the actual data stored in a place pointed to by that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

P is a pointer to int.(*p) means value at the pointer p which will be value of that int where p is pointing.(&p) will give you address of the pointer,means *(&p)=p.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to dereference the pointer to get at the value.

Try printing `*p`, as this prints the value stored at the address, this is a dereferenced pointer.

When you print `&p`, you are printing the address of the address of `p`.

Printing `p` prints the pointer to `p`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, many people prefer `int* p` over `int *p`. There is absolutely no difference between the two from a language point of view, it's just a matter of human perception.

- `int* p` says: "`p` is a pointer to an integer".
- `&p` is the memory location at which `p` is stored (ragardless of the data type of `p`).
- `p` is the pointer itself. Its value is a memory location at which an integer ist stored (except if `p == 0`).
- `*p` is (a reference to) the value that p points to.

In C, many people prefer `int *p` over `int* p`. It says: "`*p` is an integer". This has the advantage that you do not fall into traps like `int* p, q`, which declares an `int* p` and an *`int q`*.

Answer (score 0):

For pointers (e.g., int* p):

- p is the pointer (i.e., address of the pointed object)
- &p is the address of the pointer.
- *p is the pointed object (dereferencing).

For non pointers (e.g., int p):

- p is the data
- &p is its address

Comment: This is misleading, and doesn't fully answer the question. `&p` is the address of `p`, whether `p` is a pointer or not.